# C++ : How to return a Pointer to a Pointer from a function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int **j;
int Alter(int *par);
int main()
{
  static int a = 10;
  a = Alter(&a);
  std::cout << "a : " << a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
int Alter(int *par)
{
  int **j = &par;
  j += 10;
  return **j;
}
```

What's wrong with this code the output is a garbage value..
How to return a pointer to a pointer or how can we optimize this cde without using pointer to a pointer

Comment: What's wrong with this code? `j += 10;`

Comment: What do you think `j += 10;` is going to do?

Comment: @NathanOliver That is just random just want to change the value and return it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want `Alter` to increment `a` variable by 10 you will need to dereference your `j` inside it:

```
**j += 10;
^^
```

or instead of pointer to pointer, use reference:

```
int Alter(int &par);
int main()
{
  static int a = 10;
  a = Alter(a);
  std::cout << "a : " << a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
int Alter(int &par)
{
  par += 10;
  return par;
}
```

but then you dont need assignment in `a = Alter(a);`.

Answer (score 5):

Setting aside the fact that `j += 10` increments a pointer and not a value (which is not probably what you wanted to do), the main error is that, a pointer passed to a function **is passed by value in any case**.

This means that `int *j = &par` yields the address of the pointer argument on the stack passed to the `Alter` function, not the address of the passed variable.

What you need to do is to pass just a reference to the variable and modify it directly:

```
int Alter(int& par) {
  par += 10;
  return par;
} 

int main() {
  static int a = 10;
  Alter(a);
}
```

You can do it also with pointers but you'd have to use unnecessary dereference operators.

Comment: Alter should be void type. No need for returning par as it is not used.